# Backbone View does not recognize the model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Model**

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/getMiningInfo',
        defaults: {
           blocks: "",
        },
        parse: function(resp) {
           return resp;
        }
});
var info = new MyModel();
info.fetch();
```

**View**

```
var MyInfoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'table',
    id:'info',
    class:'table table-hover',
    template:_.template('<tbody><tr><td><span>Number Of Blocks</span></td>'+
                   '<td><span><%= blocks %> </span></td>'+
                '</tr></tbody>'),
    initialize: function() {
                   this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
           var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
           this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    } 
});
var myView = new MyInfoView({model: info});
myView.render();
$('#info').html(myView.el);
```

I get error for `this.model.on` and `this.model.toJSON()` as `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'on'` or `no method 'toJSON'` respectively.

Comment: First in your view its not `class` its `className`. second can you post a gist. why myInfoView and its parent both have same id?

Comment: Are you sure that `info` is what you think it is when you `new MyInfoView({model: info})`? The error suggests that it is actually a `<div>` element rather than a Backbone model.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for explaining the error. Problem was with how I was loading the files. View js was not aware of model elements because I was loading view js before model js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the view to listen for changes on the model.

```
initialize: function() {

   this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.render ); 

}
```

Backbone recommends using 'listenTo' over 'on' for garbage cleaning purposes anyway.